# How to avoid maven compile phase running liquibase:update task?

Tags: maven, liquibase

Everytime I run liquibase:update task maven recompile my project, it's quite annoying because compiling gives nothing for this liquibase task. Is it possible somehow avoid this compile task?

I use command: `mvn org.liquibase:liquibase-plugin:1.9.5.0:update`

Part of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/liquibase/properties/devDb.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You did some editing, so please confirm: when running `mvn liquibase:update` on your project containing the above pom snippet it really recompiles your project? Because it should not. You call all goal, and the respective mojo has no forked lifecycle attached.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a section in your pom.xml that lists the phase where the update goal will be executed? If not, you should be able to bind the goal to a phase that comes before compile. The liquibase maven docs show a good example:

```
<project>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
           <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.5</version>
           <configuration>                  
              <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
           </configuration>                
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>process-resources</phase>                                                                  
               <goals>
                 <goal>update</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>   
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: The question was whether he could do `mvn liquibase:update` and avoid doing a compile, not whether he could do `mvn compile` and avoid `process-resources` (aka `update`).